# Power sets of sets with nonempty intersection (Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I started learning about Set Theory and I ran into the following unproven lemma:
There exist sets $A$ and $B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ such that the power set of $A$ is equal to the power set of $A\setminus B$.

The statement is: P(A) = P(A/B) $\Leftrightarrow$  $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

I tried every possible pair of sets I could come-up with, yet I cannot find a concrete example.
I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: It's obvious that they cannot be equal, since one contains $A$ while the other does not. Or do you mean the two power sets have the same cardinality?

Comment: The cardinality can be whatever I want to. About your first answer, can you give me an example? because I don't really understand.

Comment: @OfirZcharya What do you not understand? The answer given below? What kind of example are you looking for? You can not really give an example, as this never holds. So every example, that I could give would be kind off trivial. Also specific examples would not show that this can not be true in general, but a formal proof can. The proof given is simple. If you have a question, feel free to ask. Make sure that you understand all the symbols and definitions involved.

Comment: I mean, the lemma you stated is problematic. Please check.

Comment: Every example that I found are makes the statement true.

Comment: Now that you edited your question, it is clear that you mean $A\cap B=\emptyset$ (A and B are disjoint) and not $\neq\emptyset$. I edited my answer below.

Comment: In your post you sometimes write A\B and sometimes A/B. But I suppose that you mean the set difference in all places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that this is supposed to be correct.

When $A$ and $B$ are sets with $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, then there is $x\in A$ with $x\in B$.

Then $\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}(A)$. But $\{x\}\notin\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)$. Since $\{x\}$ can not be a subset of $A\setminus B$.

Suppose otherwise, and $\{x\}\subseteq A\setminus B$. Then $x\in A\setminus B$, but $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. So $x\notin A\setminus B$. Which is a contradiction.

Edit: On your update.

When the statement is to show that $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)\Leftrightarrow~ A\cap B=\emptyset$, then we can prove this as follows:

$\Rightarrow$.

Let $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)$.

Suppose $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Then the proof given above can be applied here, to yield a contradiction.
You might want to work out the differences, or details yourself.

$\Leftarrow$:

Let $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Show $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(A\setminus B)$.

This is trivial, as $A\cap B=\emptyset$ implies that $A\setminus B=A$.

Indeed:

$A\setminus B\subseteq A$ holds always.

For: $A\subseteq A\setminus B$ let $x\in A$. Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, we have that $x\notin B$. So $x\in A\setminus B$.

So we have shown that $A=A\setminus B$ (under the assumption that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.)

Comment: So according to what do you think, the lemma is true?

Comment: @OfirZcharya No, the lemma is false. Where is it from? Do you have a source? Is this an exercise?

Comment: It is a question that my professor asked me to. But What if: A = {1}, B={2} -> then they are disjointed and (A/B = A). And if A={1},B={1,2} -> then P(A) is not equal to P(A/B).

Comment: @OfirZcharya You wrote in the question that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Is that a typo? Because that means that these sets are NOT disjoint. When they are disjoint, this is true.